# Java HashMap adding keys from two different Set sources with stream?

Tags: java, stream, hashmap

I have a `Set<String> set1` and `Set<String> set2`, as well as 2 functions `getSet1ElementScore(String s)` and `getSet2ElementScore(String s)` (that return Integers) and want to insert all elements from both sets into a HashMap as its keys, with each key's value either calculated from `getSet1ElementScore` or `getSet2ElementScore` depending on which set the key came from.

Can I use a stream to pipeline this?

Comment: Sorry, I may be misunderstanding the point of a stream. I was thinking that I could pipeline both sources and their value calculations into one call to make the whole process more efficient.

Comment: You might need to explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: Edited my question to clarify what I want to do.

Comment: Are the values in both sets disjoint? (would a string appear in both sets?)

Comment: The values are not disjoint, but the keys are. So a string would not appear in both sets, but the integer values can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I got your question right. This might achieve what you want:

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();        
        
Map<String, String> mapFromSet1 =
  set1.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), p -> getSet1ElementScore(p)) );
Map<String, String> mapFromSet2 =
  set2.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), p -> getSet2ElementScore(p)) );
        
Map<String, String> resultMap =  new HashMap<>();
resultMap.putAll(mapFromSet1);
resultMap.putAll(mapFromSet2);
```

In order to transform it in one single pipeline, I think it is possible but you'd need to use (unnecessarily) more code than that.

Answer (score 2):

You can process the elements of the two sets calling the appropriate function as:

```
Map<String, String> result = set1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getSet1ElementScore,
                    (old, new) -> old,
                    HashMap::new));
    result.putAll(
            set2.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getSet2ElementScore))
    );
```

I explicitly created a HashMap in the first processing so that it is mutable and we can merge the second into it.